# MailGun TXT records in Linode Domain Manager

Tags: mailgun, linode

I am trying to enter the TXT record for MailGun in the Linode DNS Manager.
v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all needs to be added as a TXT record in the zone I setup as 
mg.mydomain.com. The hostname for the record needs to be set as mg.mydomain.com.
The interface will not allow me to set the hostname as mg.mydomain.com.

I tried entering @ as the host,but it would not accept that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solution to the original question, but a solution. I signed up for gsuite and bypassed mailgun's validation system.